# CNG/BCrypt APIs in Windows IoT?

Tags: c++, windows, encryption, windows-10-iot-core, cng

Does Windows IOT supports CNG/BCrypt APIs?

If possible, I'd like to have some references in case it does support.

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptencrypt#requirements) is the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/buildingappsforiotcore#traditional-uwp-apps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supported. You can see that API [support desktop apps and UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptencrypt#requirements).

- But there seems no such UWP sample. You can reference "[Encrypting Data with CNG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccng/encrypting-data-with-cng)" and "[Typical CNG Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccng/typical-cng-programming)" for desktop and create your own C++ UWP application.

  Reference "[Developing UWP applications for Windows IoT Core - C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/buildingappsforiotcore#c)"
- Windows IoT Core also supports certain traditional Win32 app types such as Win32 Console Apps. There is an [IoT Core C++ Console project template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MicrosoftIoT.WindowsIoTCoreProjectTemplatesforVS15) to make it easy to build such apps using Visual Studio.

[image]